# Getting Distance in Miles with GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, django-models, geospatial, geodjango

I'm using TRUE lat and lon.   I've enabled geography in the model as I'm dealing with large distances.

The below works on the entire list of cities but how do I get the distance between a single city in miles?  Been looking all over the internet and documentation but can't seem to find an example.  Thanks.

```
pnt = AustraliaCity.objects.get(name='Hobart').point
for city in AustraliaCity.objects.distance(pnt): print(city.name, city.distance.miles)
```

Tried this and a lot of other variations but nothing sticks.

```
for city in AustraliaCity.objects.filter(pk=1).distance(pnt): print(city.name, city.distance.miles)
```

I am able to use GEOSgeometry.distance() with two points but I get a float back and can't call distance.miles to convert it.

Thanks for the advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this. Much, much easier. 
GeoPy
http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/